# Sql to find the output file with respect to input file from a table

Tags: sql, psql

I have to find out the output file name with respect to Input file name:

```
select sourceid as RawFile, destinationid from audittraillogentry 
where event ='67' 
  and innodename like '%_SFTP_%';

              rawfile               |               destinationid
------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------
 shortcodes_cdr_20140202_161239.csv | coll_DefaultCollectorGroup_0_1400591981_13
```

in result of query mentioned above my Input File Name is `shortcodes_cdr_20140202_161239.csv` (This could be multiple files & I need to find the output for all the files)

Now based on the `destinationid` of above query I find out an intermediate source ID

```
select sourceid, destinationid from audittraillogentry 
where event ='80' 
  and innodename like '%_SFTP_%' 
  and sourceid = 'coll_DefaultCollectorGroup_0_1400591981_13';

                  sourceid                  |                destinationid
--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------
 coll_DefaultCollectorGroup_0_1400591981_13 | proc_DefaultCollectorGroup_0_1400591981_120
```

Now based on the destination ID of this result I get the Output file like this

```
select destinationid 
from audittraillogentry 
where event ='68' 
  and sourceid = 'proc_DefaultCollectorGroup_0_1400591981_120';
```

Like this I need to find the Output file with respect to all the input files & I am wondering how to do this, could anyone help me with this, this would be a great help

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the three queries as being three queries off three *different* tables, then you just need to join them (... as far as I understand your requirement). Something like this may be what you are looking for:

```
select e68.destinationid 
from audittraillogentry e68, 
  audittraillogentry e80, 
  audittraillogentry e67 
where e67.event='67'
  and e67.innodename like '%_SFTP_%'
  and e67.destinationid=e80.sourceid
  and e80.event='80'
  and e80.innodename like '%_SFTP_%'
  and e80.destinationid=e68.sourceid
  and e68.event='68';
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99725a/1).

Views can really be handy if you need to do this a lot - a view for common event types for example.

Comment: Thanks wwkudu,  I had already found the answer for the same, anyways thanks a lot :)